# How to change the flot bar fill and border color?

Tags: javascript, json, codeigniter, flot

I have created a user graph for my codeigniter project. The bar fill is set at the default. But I would like the **BARS** to change it so it looks like the bars on this image: http://www.riwakawebsitedesigns.com/offsite/images/userchart.PNG

I echo the data from my controller. But just would like to know how to make bars and bar-border look like the image above.

When I add these `shadowSize: 0, colors: ['#9FD5F1', '#1065D2'],` to the series bar it does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

   var data = <?php echo $data;?>;

    $.plot($("#chart-user"), [data],  {
        series: {

            bars: { 
                shadowSize: 0,
                show: true,
                fill: true,
                    //fillColor: '#9FD5F1'
            },
            grid: {
              backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
              hoverable: true
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this below to make it work added color below series

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

   var data = <?php echo $data;?>;

    $.plot($("#chart-user"), [data],  {
        series: {
                color: '#1065D2',
            bars: { 
                    shadowSize: 0,
                show: true,
                fill: true,
            },
            grid: {
              backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
              hoverable: true
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer to this. For Bars you specify the fillColor for each series. Then the global Series Colors. The Bar will be filled with the fillColor and use the Colors for the lines.

The below example is using 2 different data arrays d1 (Absent Time), d2 (Time Worked) and stacks for each bar for different time spans

E.g:

```
var chartOptions = {
    xaxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        ticks: [[25, '25%'], [50, '50%'], [75, '75%'], [100, '100%']]
    }, 
    yaxis: {
        ticks:   [[1, 'Today'], [2, 'Yesterday'], [3, 'This Week'],[4, 'Last Week']],
        position: 'right',
        font: { size: 12 }
    },
    series: {
        stack : true,
        bars: {
            horizontal: true,
            show: true
        }
    },
    colors: ['rgb(52,95,14)', 'rgb(108,105,19)'],
};
$.plot($('#placeHolder'), [{ data:d1, bars:{fillColor: 'rgb(194, 238, 155)', fill: 0.9}}, { data:d2, bars:{fillColor: 'rgb(241, 239, 177)', fill: 0.9}}], chartOptions);
```

[The displayed chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfSKf.png)